# Operator IF doesnt check condition of values in cmd

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

Hi everyone I writing little .bat file and seemed for I was ended but I got error. Operator IF does not checking Permission value and Free space conditions of values and are not compering. All the time I get "false" even when the free space on disc D is less then 25Gb (26,843,545,600 bits)
My code looks such:

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set permissiblevalue=26,843,545,600
set permissiblevalue=%permissiblevalue:,=%

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir d:\') do (
    set bytesfree=%%a
)

set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%

if %permissiblevalue% leq %bytesfree% (
    The disk D is checking.....
) else (
    echo msgbox "Lacks of free space on disk D. Klick OK for delete files!!!" > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    wscript %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
    %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "d:\"
)

exit
```

Please explain to me Where is the mistake

Comment: the output of `dir` gives the number of **bytes** free. No one measures disk data size in bits. And `leq` does a lexicographic string comparison so obviously it won't work unless you pad the string properly, for example if there are only 3027 bytes free then it'll compare larger than 26GB

Comment: I geting two values when I use echo commands ```echo %permissiblevalue%
echo %bytesfree%``` 26843545600
104231993344 according to my research
And I need just to compare the first variable with the second. how to do it? If the first value of the second and display the result

Comment: `dir` supports an option `/-C` to output byte values without the thousands separator…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two arguments to `if` are both pure numeric strings, `cmd` will convert them to integers and compare them as integers. **BUT** `cmd` is limited to 2^31 and mechanically processes the string character-by-character, left-to-right, multiplying by 10 and adding the next value, so any value greater than 2147483647 will be processed incorrectly (but won't generate en error).

Consequently, if you are using large numbers, you need to force `cmd` to interpret them as strings. This is easily done by "quoting each string".
**BUT** a string comparison is performed character-by-character, so you need to leading-0-fill each so that they are the same length.

To do this :

```
set "zeroes=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
set "var=%zeroes%%var%"
set "var=%var:~-20%"
```

Which prepends a series of `0` characters to the current value of `var`, then sets `var` to the last 20 characters of the result.

You can then safely use `if "%var%" leq "%someothervar%"`

Tip : Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign a terminal `\`, Space or `"` - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.